# <c:foreach> is not recogized! . ArrayList iteration in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, jstl, taglib

I went through all of the posts related to JSTL and arrayList , still couldn't find the solution.

I have been trying to iterate an ArrayList over a jsp file using taglib. 
I have included latest jstl 1.2 jar in my build path.
Have configured the taglib properly.

But still get an error infront of the line which uses

```
 <c:forEach>
```

tag. 
It says

```
 <c:foreach>not recognized!,
```

yes it is showing error with a 'e' in forEach !

Please find my code below.

Controller code :

```
   List<String> rolesList = new ArrayList<String>();
   rolesList.add(ga.getAuthority());
```

JSP Code :

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

   <select>
      <c:forEach items="${rolesList}" var="role">
             <option>${role}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

Comment: Which server are you using? This won't work in old server versions.

Comment: Read this http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/JstlTagLibDefinitions

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 7.
@HardikMishra : I added both newer versions of the jar as mentioned in that link. Doesnt'seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the jstl 1.2 jar in your RUNTIME classpath? That's where it counts!

Comment: I'm still a rookie, it would be great if you could elaborate that.
I have included it as an external jar in my buildpath along with other jars like spring, hibernate etc., Is there another place where i should drop this jstl jar?

Comment: If your build tool builds a proper war, then you should find it in the lib folder inside the war file. A war file is a zip file so any zip file utility will be able to open for you to have a look inside. There's always the option of putting a copy of the file in your application server's lib folder. If you're using Tomcat you'll find it at the top level in the Tomcat folder.

Comment: I get what RUNTIME classpath means now.Thanks for the explainiation @Tommy B the JSTL 1.2 jar is there inside it, but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced same problem when i include jsf in jsp

Then i download latest jstl jar and included inside project lib,

Then added below code in header

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and changed $ into # beacause it not visible array list in runtime, i changed your code  its working for me

your code

```
<select>
      <c:forEach items="${rolesList}" var="role">
             <option>${role}</option>
        </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I changed into

```
 <select>
      <c:forEach var="list" items="#{Test.rolesList}" var="role">
             <option>${list.role}</option>
        </c:forEach>
</select>
```

**Note:**
Test is a Managedbean 
`@ManagedBean(name="Test")` in back bean code

Thank you

Comment: As to using `#{}` instead of `${}`, OP doesn't seem to indicate anywhere that he is using JSF.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have included latest jstl 1.2 jar in my build path.*

This is not the entirely correct approach.

Assuming that you're using Eclipse, the JAR file should be dropped in the project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Really nothing more needs to be done.  You do not need to fiddle in the *Build Path* property of the project. You should undo everything which you did there in an attempt to "fix" the problem.

If you really insist in having the JAR outside the project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder for some reason, then you should not have edited the *Build Path* property, but instead the *Deployment Assembly* property. This will take care that the JAR also *actually* ends up in the `/WEB-INF/lib` of the built and deployed WAR.